# React datePicker (NextJs)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, next.js

I want to work with `datePicker` in reactJS(Next JS)
all works normally but when I'm switching my browser to responsive, the icon disappears.
who can help me solve this issue

here is my code

```
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField'
import AdapterDateFns from '@mui/lab/AdapterDateFns'
import LocalizationProvider from '@mui/lab/LocalizationProvider'
import DatePicker from '@mui/lab/DatePicker'
import CalendarMonthIcon from '@mui/icons-material/CalendarMonth'
import StaticDatePicker from '@mui/lab/DatePicker'
const [value, setValue] = useState(null)

<LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
  <StaticDatePicker
    displayStaticWrapperAs="desktop"
    label="Week picker"
    value={value}
    onChange={(newValue) => {
      setValue(newValue)
    }}
    renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
    inputFormat="'Week of' MMM d"
  />
</LocalizationProvider>
```

[image]

Comment: What happens if you remove the `displayStaticWrapperAs="desktop"` attribute?

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs there are two versions of the component and the mobile one does not have an icon https://mui.com/components/date-picker/#responsiveness, you can test it there and the responsive one changes

Comment: Thank you so much.
I already found needed component